# Can I have Global Menu within the Gnome Fallback Session?

Tags: appmenu, gnome-classic

My Default Unity session is too heavy to my laptop now (4 years old machine) and it's constantly hanging. I installed the fallback session to get more responsiveness of the whole system, but now i don't have a global menu, and by that, I lose some screen space..minimal, but I still want them... Is that a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

You can get this by installing the [indicator-applet-appmenu [image: Install indicator-applet-appmenu]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/indicator-applet-appmenu) package in the Software Center, Synaptic, or with `apt-get`.

I had to log out an back in to get it to show up in my list of panel widgets to add.

Comment: Cool, will this work for Ubuntu 12.10 as well?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but still valid (top Google result) and I might add a useful detail to Ian and Eliah's answer.

The `indicator-applet-appmenu` pointed out above is excellent, but by itself it doesn't fully replace the functionality you find in Unity: with the `indicator-applet-appmenu`, a maximized window *still has its own title bar*, whereas in Unity the global menu *doubles* as title bar (depending on whether the mouse is hovering on it or not), which saves a little extra vertical space.

Something very close can be achieved with an extra tweak: add the `indicator-applet-appmenu` to the top Gnome panel, then configure that panel to auto-hide. Like that, if the active window is maximized, its title bar will occupy the very top of the screen,  making better use of vertical space; but, if the mouse touches the top edge of the screen, the top panel will slide down, revealing the application's menu.

Disabling "Expand" in the top panel's properties can also be useful, as it will prevent the panel from sliding on top of the window's close/minimize/maximize buttons, which can be annoying.